# Concat multiple localizer strings

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I concat two localizer strings in asp.net core with razor? I got a strange output when I do the following.

**createMenu.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Localizer["create"]+" "+@Localizer["menu"];
}
```

**Output**

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString
```

When I only use one localizer it works like it should work.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Localizer["create"].Value+" "+@Localizer["menu"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
ViewBag.Title = @(String.Format("{0} {1}", Localizer["create"], Localizer["menu"]))
```

Comment: Found solution: You have to call the value function from the LocalizedHtmlString: @Localizer["create"].Value+" "+@Localizer["menu"].Value;
I presume that when you only call one localizer (without + sign) it automatically cast the value to string